# Arrange in the order of their reactivity of SN2 reaction

Tags: nucleophilic-substitution, reaction-order

[image]

Here in case of (1) it is more favorable towards S<sub>N</sub>1 reaction as it will create benzyl carbocation which is very stable.

(2) Here it is more favorable towards S<sub>N</sub>1 as it is first of all allyl carbocation and in resonance with the benzene and the double bond.

(3) It is allyl carbocation, so it is less favorable to S<sub>N</sub>1 than (1) and more favorable to S<sub>N</sub>2.

(4) It is the most favorable towards S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction.

Hence the order of reactivity towards S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction should be

(4) > (3) > (1) > (2)

But the answer is

(2) > (1) > (3) > (4)

Why?

Comment: Are you sure the question is about $SN_2$ and not $SN_1$? Because your classification is correct with $SN_2$

Comment: Yeah i am sure i can send the question picture if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order you've given is absolutely correct with respect to SN2, I believe, the question needs to be authenticated once again, as the order for SN1 would be the exact reverse of this, which is as given in the answer to your question.